# IF statement that shows a different text according to the shopping cart amount

Tags: shopping-cart, liquid

I need to make an IF statement script on my Shopping Cart, which displays a different text depending on the amount in the basket. Currently I only have two options. IF/ELSE. How do I make several IF statements which changes on a specific amount?

So far I've made this, which only applies to an amount below/beyond 1000:

```
{% assign totalCart = 0 %}
            {% for item in cart.items %}
            {% assign totalCart = totalCart | plus:item.totalCart_raw %}
            {% endfor %}

    {% comment %}
If the amount 
{% endcomment %}

{% if totalCart >= 1000 %}

               Volume Discount 20% 

                {%else%}        

               Volume Discount available 30% 
            {%endif%}
```

Comment: you could use a `case` + `when` statement? or maybe chain `if` + `elsif` + `else` depends on what exactly you are trying to do. Edit: [Documentation](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/control-flow/)

Comment: @UnholySheep Is a case+when statement the best option, when I need 5 different text's depending on the amount?

Comment: most likely, although it depends. `case` + `when` can only do equality comparisons, not greater/smaller comparisons. In that case you would have to use `if` + `elsif` + `else`

Comment: Okay, I need 5 different greater/smaller comparisons. How do I write the code with 5 different if + elseif + else statements? Could you help me with an example @UnholySheep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of using `if` + `elsif` (based on the code in the question)

```
{% assign totalCart = 0 %}
            {% for item in cart.items %}
            {% assign totalCart = totalCart | plus:item.totalCart_raw %}
            {% endfor %}

    {% comment %}
If the amount 
{% endcomment %}

{% if totalCart < 1000 %}
Volume Discount 20% use this code 
{% elsif totalCart < 2000 %}
Volume Discount available 30% use this code
{% elsif totalCart < 3000 %}
Volume Discount available 40% use this code
{% elsif totalCart < 4000 %}
Volume Discount available 50% use this code
{% elsif totalCart > 4000 %}
Volume Discount available 60% use this code
{% endif%}
```

Comment: Perfect . I made some small modifications, but this solves my problem perfectly. Didn't know I could just use serveral elseif. Thank you for your help and time.